# Does angular support synchronous call or asynchronous call by default.?

Tags: angularjs, xmlhttprequest

Does angular support synchronous call or asynchronous cal be default?

Comment: No it doesn't support..I'd suggest don't go for synchronous calls on browser as they hangs browser(bad user experience), use promise chain/callbacks for dealing with such situation

Answer (score 0):

AngularJs supports async requests by default.

If you look at the code in General Usage the comments explain what is happening.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests are always asynchronous.

Angular exposes the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) service, which allows you to do all http requests to the server. All the function calls return a promise object, which allows you to code in a clean *synchronous way*.

You can also use additional high level modules like [ng-resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource), but they are all asynchronous (which is a good thing).

Answer (score 0):

Browsers make synchronous HTTP requests to a URL.

JavaScript is the language of the browser.  JavaScript allows you to make asynchronous AJAX calls.  Since angular is written in JavaScript, it can make asynch calls too.

The answer is that you can make synchronous or asynchronous HTTP requests from a browser.  Since Angular runs in the browser, it can too.